# Add a divider on top of a bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

Is there a way to add a divider like this one to the top of a `BottomNavigationBar()`? I got it for the `AppBar()` as you can see below:

[image: AppBar() with Divider()]

```
appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          _views[_index]['title'],
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(10),
          child: Divider(
            thickness: 2,
            height: 0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

But I wonder if there is a way to do the same with the `BottomNavigationBar()`.

It should look like this in the end:

[image: BottomNavigationBar()]

Comment: you can use the ``Divider()`` widget at the start of your scaffold body contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it like this:

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          _views[_index]['view'],
          Spacer(),
          Divider(
            thickness: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

I just added a `Divider()` inside the `body` property under the actual content of the `Scaffold()` and pushed it down with a `Spacer()`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to add a line(Divider) above the bottom navigation bar is to wrap it with a container and add only the top border to the container.
Here's the sample code how to do this,

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Styles.whiteColor,
      body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xffAEADB2),
              width: 0.3,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xffAEADB2),
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          enableFeedback: false,
         items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          iconSize: 40,
          elevation: 0,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`AppBar` has the `leading` property

Use a colored container inside a `PreferredSize` widget for the `AppBar` widget's top

```
AppBar(
  title: Text("Title"),
  leading: PreferredSize(
    child: Container(color: colors.Black, height: 5.0),
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(5.0),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Yes I solved it like this in the app bar, but how do I do the same in a bottom navigation bar?

Comment: @devAcronym using the leading property